# Iterating through different classes of another script in Python

Tags: python, loops, class, import, module

I have a script with different classes. Now I need to import that script and iterate through all the classes in Python. I don't know with what library that could be possible?

For exaple there is foo.py with different classes:

```
#foo.py
class a():
   print("a")

class b():
   print("b")

class c():
   print("c")
```

Also there is another script myscript.py that I want to import foo.py and loop over all the classes (Pseudocode) :

```
#myscript.py
import foo
for c in foo.classes:
    #do something...
```

I'm wondering if there is a library that I can do that.

Comment: Because myscript.py is a test script and I need to test all of those classes in another platform. 
I tried to get the name of the classes and create a list of those with importlib and inspect:

for name, cls in inspect.getmembers(importlib.import_module('foo'), inspect.isclass):

but then I cannot access to the classes with just the names.

Comment: Have you looked at using `unittest`, which is in the standard library? Most, if not all, test frameworks supply some sort of test discovery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dir()` & `getattr()` to get what you want:

```
import foo

for symbol in dir(foo):
    # ignore dunder-members
    if symbol.startswith('_'):
        continue
    print(symbol)
    # here's your class 
    cl = getattr(foo, symbol)
    # here's how you can make an object
    obj = cl()
    print(obj)
```

Output:

```
a
<foo.a object at 0x10e1339a0>
b
<foo.b object at 0x10e133c70>
c
<foo.c object at 0x10e1339a0>
```

However, this is not really maintainable code - I'd suggest refactoring to ensure this is not required.

Comment: Now I tried dir(), it works and it returns all the classes names. Another problem is that in those classes also there are another classes that I need to access to them too!
Then if we have symbol as a class name, I cannot access to foo.symbol! 
I get this error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'symbol'

Comment: You can apply `dir` on the class object `cl` & get those inner classes. Then use the same `getattr` way to access them.

Comment: Nice!! I got all of them now! Thank you!